# App updates not getting pushed to users

Tags: android

Does anyone know why updates for a new version of an existing Android app would not be sent to existing users from the Market?

I recently pushed a few updates to my app hosted in the Android Market but I have received word that users might be having to uninstall and completely re-install my app to get the update as opposed to the normal update process.

I recently turned of Google's copy protection feature because it is getting deprecated soon. Could it be related to that?

I am signing it with the same key. The package name has stayed the same. I just uploaded a new .apk file and activated it.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciate.

[Edit:] I have updated my versionCode for each new release.

Comment: This may sound silly, but did you change the versionCode?

Comment: I should have included that in my original post. I have updated my versionCode each release.

Comment: First off, how _recently_ did you update it? AFAIK, updates aren't pushed out immediately - usually staggered. Also, did that manual uninstall/reinstall apply to _all_ users? (did the auto update work for _any_?)

Comment: Good questions. I will have to gather more data to answer those. Do you know how often AFAIK updates are usually pushed? Are we talking a few hours? daily? weekly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it does just take time for the updates to get pushed out. Thanks for everyone's comments!

As a side note, I was able to confirm with Google that even if you unpublish then republish your app ALL users should still get the updates. (http://matthew-moses.com/main/2012/01/31/pushing-updates-to-previously-unpublished-applications-in-the-android-market-place/)